# low value with % from Excel in Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

How to read numeric data from Excel when we have low number?

For example, I have

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456789012 | 0.1% | 0.02% | 0.003% | 0.0004% | 0.0005% |

And when I read my data like

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(((XSSFCell)cell).getRawValue()));
```

I get

```
1234567
0.001
0.00020000000000000001
0.000030000000000000001
0.0000039999999999999998
4.9999999999999998E-8
```

But, If I change my line to that view

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(cell.getNumericValue());

1234567
0.001000000000000000000020816681711....
0.000200000000000000000009584347204....
and etc
```

So, my question is how to parse that line in correct format?
How to get 0.1 and 0.02 and etc? And it doesn't matter in String or in number. Although I will have to make some mathematical actions with that numbers after all, but anyway, I have to get correct numbers first of all.

Comment: Try https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html#formatCellValue-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell-

Answer (score 3):

If the need is getting all cell values in the same format as Excel shows them in it's GUI, then [DataFormatter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) can be used. Using current `apache poi` version `5.2.2` this is as simple as using `DataFormatter.formatCellValue(Cell cell)` which returns a `String` showing the cell value in the same format as Excel shows it. This also works for formula cells when `DataFormatter.setUseCachedValuesForFormulaCells(true)` is set.

But if the cell values shall be used dependent of their types, for example dates as dates, numbers as numbers, booleans as booleans, ... and only strings as strings, then reading by cell type is necessary. And then one needs to know how Excel stores numeric cell values.

Excel stores all numeric values as double values.

In Excel date/time values also are numeric values. There a value of 1.0 means one day, starting on 1900-01-01. So 1.0 is 1900-01-01, 2.0 is 1900-01-02 and so on. Today, 2022-06-07, is the numeric value 44,719.0. Time values are decimal values between 0.00 and 1.00. One hour is 1.0/24.0, one minute is 1.0/24.0/60.0, one second is 1.0/24.0/60.0/60.0. That's why only having the numeric cell value one cannot determine whether this is a date/time or not. Only having the cell data format from the cell style, this is detectable. Thats why `apache poi` provides `DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(Cell cell)` to detect whether a cell is date formatted.

The percent format also is such a special case. In Excel a value of 1.0 means 100%, 0.5 means 50% and so on. So if one get a numeric cell value of 0.5 whthout further knowledge, then it is not detectible whether this is a percent value or not. Here one also needs the cell data format from the cell style . But for this case `apache poi`does not provide any utility methods. So one needs to detect this oneself.

The following code shows all this.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

class ReadExcel {
    
 static void readAsStrings(Workbook workbook) {
  DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter(java.util.Locale.US);
  dataFormatter.setUseCachedValuesForFormulaCells(true);
  String cellValue = "";

  for (Sheet sheet: workbook) {
   System.out.println("Sheet " + sheet.getSheetName());
   for (Row row : sheet) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
     cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
     System.out.println(cell.getAddress() + ":" + cellValue);
     // do something with cellValue
    }
   }
  }
 } 
 
 static boolean isCellPercentFormatted(Cell cell) {
  if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC || cell.getCachedFormulaResultType() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
   CellStyle cellStyle = cell.getCellStyle();
   if (cellStyle.getDataFormat() == (short)0x9 || cellStyle.getDataFormat() == (short)0xA) return true;
   String dataFormatString = cellStyle.getDataFormatString();
   String[] posNegZeroTextFormat = dataFormatString.split(";");
   for (int i = 0; i < posNegZeroTextFormat.length; i++) {
    if (posNegZeroTextFormat[i].endsWith("%")) return true; 
   }
   if (dataFormatString.endsWith("%")) return true;
  }
  return false;
 }
 
 static double getPercentCellValue(Cell cell) {
  double cellValue = cell.getNumericCellValue();
  double percentValue = cellValue * 100d;
  return percentValue;
 }
 
 static void handleCellByType(CellType cellType, Cell cell) {
  switch (cellType) {
   case STRING:
    System.out.println(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
    break;
   case NUMERIC:
    if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
     System.out.println(cell.getDateCellValue());
    } else if (isCellPercentFormatted(cell)) {
     System.out.println(getPercentCellValue(cell));
    } else {
     System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
    }
    break;
   case BOOLEAN:
    System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
    break;
   case FORMULA:
    System.out.println(cell.getCellFormula());
    //probably evaluate the formula first
    handleCellByType(cell.getCachedFormulaResultType(), cell);
    break;
   case ERROR:
    System.out.println(cell.getErrorCellValue());
    break;
   case BLANK:
    System.out.println();
    break;
   default:
    System.out.println();
  } 
 }
 
 static void readByType(Workbook workbook) { 
  for (Sheet sheet: workbook) {
   System.out.println("Sheet " + sheet.getSheetName());
   for (Row row : sheet) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
     handleCellByType(cell.getCellType(), cell);
    }
   }
  } 
 }
    
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  
  try (
   Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelExample.xlsx"));
   //Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelExample.xls"));
   ) {
   
   readAsStrings(workbook);
   
   readByType(workbook);
   
  }  
 }
}
```

Having your sample sheet, the `readAsStrings` prints:

```
Sheet Sheet1
A1:123456789012
B1:0.1%
C1:0.02%
D1:0.003%
E1:0.0004%
F1:0.0005%
```

And the `readByType` prints:

```
Sheet Sheet1
1.23456789012E11
0.1
0.02
0.003
3.9999999999999996E-4
5.0E-4
```

Comment: I voted your answer, but it wasn`t my solution. It was about Serialization and BigDecimal.toString() returns incorrect value comparing with toPlainString().
I make CustomBigDecimalSerialator for that and solved my problem.